# Why can't I const_cast the return of the conversion operator?

Tags: c++, const-cast

I've got a conversion operator that returns a const pointer, and I need to const_cast it. However, that doesn't work, at least under MSVC8. The following code reproduces my problem:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    operator const int* () {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass obj;
    int* myPtr;
    // compiles
    const int* myConstPtr = obj;
    // compiles
    myPtr = const_cast<int*>(myConstPtr);
    // doesn't compile (C2440: 'const_cast' : cannot convert from 'MyClass' to 'int *')
    myPtr = const_cast<int*>(obj);
}
```

Why is that? It seems counter-intuitive. Thanks!

Comment: Are you really trying to return a null pointer with `const int*`? It's also typically bad practice to be able to silently cast a class into a pointer to a primitive. (For example, `std::string` cannot be cast into `const char*` but instead provides a method `.c_str()` that returns a pointer to its data. This is much safer because then the programmer has to be very aware of what he is doing.)

Comment: @Seth: Thanks. This is not my real code; it's just something I wrote to reproduce the error I'm getting! Rest assured, I'm not returning null pointers on purpose :-) In my case, the class is a thin wrapper around a byte array, and I would like its clients to use it as if it were one.

Comment: If you intend you users to be able to manipulate the bytearray directly then you should give them a non-const `operator int*()`. In general giving only the const version implies you allow reads but not modifies. Forcing the users to do a `const_cast` is a mistake in my book.

Comment: @Matt. The array _is_ readonly: the problem at hand is a legacy API whose designer forgot to mark one of the inputs as `const`!

Comment: ok, then you have a case where it makes sense to use `const_cast` :)

Comment: And I do agree with Seth, unless you have a strong reason to need the implicit casting, go with a method that returns the pointer like `std::string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it work you have to do :

```
myPtr = const_cast<int*>(static_cast<const int*>(obj));
```

When you const_cast directly, the compiler look for the cast operator to int*.

Answer (score 2):

`const_cast` can only change the constness of a type. If you want to call the implicit operator you have you need a `static_cast` and then a `const_cast`. While it's annoying it makes sure you are explicit in what you are doing.

```
myPtr = const_cast<int*>(static_cast<const int*>(obj));
```

You can also use the old school c-style cast operator

```
myPtr = (int*)(const int*)obj;
```

But this is highly discouraged for several reasons:

- It isn't grepable
- You can very easily do more than you intended. Most of the time you don't want to mess with `const_cast` type operations and using `static_cast` enforces this. In fact you very rarely want a `const_cast`. If you find yourself doing it regularly you have some design mistakes.

Edit: I was slightly off, I fixed it now. It makes the c-style cast a little uglier

Comment: The C-style cast is also discouraged in this case for the reason that it doesn't compile - he's trying to cast an instance of MyClass, not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use const_cast to convert to a non-const pointer of the same type (to cast away constness). To cast between unrelated types you need reinterpret_cast.

Comment: Thanks! I just thought the compiler would figure out `MyClass` can be converted to `int*` automatically, as it did in "`const int* myConstPtr = obj`"

Comment: No, no, no! He created conversion operator from MyClass to int * so the types *are* related. static_cast is apropriate. reinterpret_cast won't invoke the operator. Luckily it won't compile as obj is not a pointer and reinterpret_cast requires either a pointer or an integer type and obj is neither.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `const_cast<>` as a function template

```
template <typename Target, typename Source>
Target const_cast( Source src );
```

(that's not how it's implemented, but it helps here to imagine it was). Then `Source` is deduced as `MyClass`, and there's nothing `const_cast` can do to get an int* from a MyClass.

What you want is either of the following:

```
const_cast<int*>( static_cast<const int*>(obj) /* invokes operator const int* */ );
// or
const_cast<int*>( obj.operator const int*() );
```

Comment: Yes, `myPtr = const_cast<int*>(obj.operator const int *());` does work! That is one ugly piece of code, though.

Answer (score -1):

Probably it would be clearer to your compiler if you do something like:

```
myPtr = const_cast<int*>(obj());
```

I haven't tried yet, thought.

EDIT:
Shouldn't the operator declaration be something like:

```
const int* operator () {
```

Comment: Doesn't work: C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments.

Comment: I've always used: const int* operator() () { ... } - not sure where the OP's function definition came from, but apparently it compiles.

Comment: The OP's definition is of a conversion operator to const int*. Samir's definition is of the "function call" operator() taking no parameters and returning const int*. Although the two operators have the same inputs and output, they are used by the compiler in different situations.

Comment: -1, the question is about conversion operator, not `operator()`.

Comment: Should I leave this answer for people that make the same mistake as me? Or should I just delete it?